# Extruding curve to 2D

Tags: line, polygon

I have a curve made out of line segments. It looks something like the following:

[image]

I want to create a 2d polygon out of this, with a uniform width everywhere, something like the following:

[image]

(Imagine it's the same width everywhere)

Is there an algorithm, which does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeking what is called the *curve offset*. This is a heavily studied problem. Software abounds, e.g., you can offset within Adobe Illustrator.
The task is especially challenging for self-intersecting curves, as illustrated below.

---

[image: CurveOffsets]

---

Here is one paper (which indlues the above figure):

> Liu, Xu-Zheng, Jun-Hai Yong, Guo-Qin Zheng, and Jia-Guang Sun. "An offset algorithm for polyline curves." *Computers in Industry* 58, no. 3 (2007): 240-254.

Search for "curve offset algorithms."